# How come I got repeated portions in my XML builder?

Tags: xml, jsp

I'm trying to use JSP to store form data in XML file. However, I got repeated lines after I input multiple entries like this:

(seems when record 2 is appended, the whole thing before record 2 is rewritten)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Students>
<Name>test1</Name>
<Title>balala</Title>
<URL>www.kaka.com</URL>
</Students>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Students>
<Name>test1</Name>
<Title>balala</Title>
<URL>www.kaka.com</URL>
<Name>test2</Name>
<Title>nana</Title>
<URL>www.lolo.com</URL>
</Students>
```

The code I'm using:

```
<body>
    <h3>Get Data from the form</h3>
    <p>
    <%
       //Get data from the form
       String name= request.getParameter("name");
       String title=request.getParameter("title");
       String url= request.getParameter("url");
   %>


  <%!


      public void createXmlTree(String name,String title,String url) throws Exception {


        Element root;
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        File file = new File("C:/Users/webservstu/Documents/new.xml");
        if (file.exists())
        {
          doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
          root = doc.getDocumentElement();
          String sr = root.getNodeName();
        }
         else
        {

          System.out.println(name);
          root = doc.createElement("Students");
          doc.appendChild(root);
        }


        Element child1 = doc.createElement("Name");
        root.appendChild(child1);

        Text text1 = doc.createTextNode(name);
        child1.appendChild(text1);

        Element child2 = doc.createElement("Title");
        root.appendChild(child2);

        Text text2 = doc.createTextNode(title);
        child2.appendChild(text2);

        Element child3 = doc.createElement("URL");
        root.appendChild(child3);

        Text text3 = doc.createTextNode(url);
        child3.appendChild(text3);

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");


        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        String xmlString = sw.toString();
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file,true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write(xmlString);
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();

    }%>


<%


  try
  {

    createXmlTree(name,title,url);

    out.println("<b>Xml File Created Successfully</b>");
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println(e);
  }

  %>

    <br>


    </p>
    <hr>

    <p><font size="2">*Direct Submission*</font></p>

    </body>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file,true);
```

Your second argument is to *append* to the end of the file.

On the other hand, I would recommend against just changing this - I'd suggest using `FileOutputStream` instead and creating a `StreamResult` directly from that, so it writes it *straight* to the file without any other encodings getting in the way. As it is, you'll be using the platform default encoding to write the text, even though the text itself declares that it's in UTF-8.

Heck, you don't even need to create the `FileOutputStream` yourself - you can create a `StreamResult` directly from the `File`.

Comment: Thanks Jon, after I first tried to change the second argument to false. It worked. However, the newly added record is also included in the root category "Student". Anyway to make it in a new "Student" wrapper? Sorry I'm kind new to this. Thanks.

Comment: @eastboundr: As I say, you should change to not use `FileWriter` anyway... but if you want to create a new `Student` element, you're going to have to call `doc.createElement("Student")` and add all the elements to *that* element instead of directly to the root node.